# wasn't able to write the buffer stream into a newly created directory in nodeJs

Tags: node.js

I had to create a directory named stuff and write the stream into a text file inside the "stuff" directory. but, because the code in NodeJs doesn't execute in a serial fashion, I m getting an error which says the directory doesn't exist. any help would be appreciated. the code is pasted below.

```
var http = require("http");

var fs = require("fs");

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/readMe.txt","UTF-8");

  var writeStream;

  fs.mkdir("stuff",function(){

     writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+"/stuff/writeMe.txt");

 });

readStream.on("data",function(chunk){

writeStream.write(chunk);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the folder creation function, it returns instantly. But the callback function is executed only when the folder has been created (or creation has failed.)

```
fs.mkdir("stuff",function(){
    // executed after folder creation
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+"/stuff/writeMe.txt");
});
// executed instantly
```

In your current code, when you try to write to the folder, it has not been created yet, and `writeStream` is `undefined`.

So you need to write to the folder *after* it's been created:

```
fs.mkdir("stuff",function(){
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+"/stuff/writeMe.txt");
    readStream.on("data",function(chunk){
        writeStream.write(chunk);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. that helped